# Linked server Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider

Tags: sql, linked-server

I am trying to create linked server to a application which uses pervasive database i setup everything right but i kept getting `Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL"`
i tried both 32 and 64 ODBC Data source Administration.
Here is SQL Server version infomation

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22 (X64) 
    Jul  9 2008 14:17:44 
    Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation
    Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: )
```

i tried a lot trying to fix this but the test fails. ODBC connection using `Pervasive ODBC Interface` tested and works great.

> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "serverName".
>   OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "serverName" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified". (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Comment: Have you tried setting up a DSN and then setting up your linked server based on that? I don't have experience with this particular service but in the past I have needed to setup DSNs for certain kinds of data sources.

Comment: @mroach yes that's what i did, i been working on this almost for a week, what thing do i have to check?

Answer (score 4):

if you try to create the linked server using studio and the various menus, a small detail is not saved in the connection string, which is the database! (see last bit of the connection string)

Try this:It works for me

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server='MYSQL',
   @srvproduct='MySQL',
       @provider='MSDASQL', @provstr='DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1
       Driver};SERVER=HOST;Port=3306;USER=uid;PASSWORD=pw;OPTION=3;DATABASE=mydb';
```

Answer (score 0):

First I Downloaded the last ODBC Driver from: [ODBC Driver Link](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) and Installed it.

After in SQL Management Studio I inserted the code below:

"I changed driver's description to: "MySQL: 8.0" and setting RPC to allow Remote Procedure Call if was important".

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver 
        @server = N'LKD_MYSQL', 
        @srvproduct=N'MySQL', 
        @provider=N'MSDASQL', 
        @provstr=N'Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver};DATABASE=database;OPTION=3;PASSWORD=****;USER=user;SERVER=host'

GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LKD_MYSQL', @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LKD_MYSQL', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LKD_MYSQL', @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LKD_MYSQL', @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LKD_MYSQL', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LKD_MYSQL', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LKD_MYSQL', @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LKD_MYSQL', @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LKD_MYSQL', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LKD_MYSQL', @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LKD_MYSQL', @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LKD_MYSQL', @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LKD_MYSQL', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'true'
GO

USE [master]
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = N'LKD_MYSQL', @locallogin = NULL , @useself = N'False'
GO
```

sample of select:

```
select * from openquery(LKD_MYSQL,'select * from database.table')
```

Answer (score 0):

We also facing the same kind of issue and resolved by changing mysql login password as it's using ; in end of password, hope this will resolve your issue.